# Unwanted keyframe in dope sheet

Tags: animation, keyframes, dopesheet

There is an unwanted keyframe in my dopesheet. I can't delete it, move it, unselect it, etc. It doesn't seem to be connected to any object/bone.

[image]

It's the keyframe you can see to the far right.

It's similar in behaviour to what this guy posted on youtube(jump to 00:15):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9RSKKb5HcBI#t=15s

What is this?

Extra info:
I tried installing a different build. But both Blender 2.71 and 2.72b behave like this(same .blend though).

I have seen this behaviour before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This keyframe is related to an object currently not editable because of selection issues. If you engage the *little phantom* button near the arrow in the header of your dopesheet window, it should become editable (and disengage the arrow).

Comment: That solved it! But the keyframe shouldn't really show up like this though, should it? Is it a bug?

Comment: It's his normal behavior, according to what is selected in the 3d window and what is selected in the dopesheet window: the arrow lets you see only the selected item, the phantom lets you work also on unselected objects!